# error "net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID" in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to make an http request like:

```
function foo() {
$.ajax({
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            url: "https://192.168.xxx.xxx/api/Domains/GetDomains/false",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            }            
        });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    foo();
});
```

But Im getting error:

[image]

I tried with postman and it worked, why Im getting this error when I try via code?

Comment: You can not make a request to your IP address as SSL (https) make it http://

Comment: https://www.guildcafe.com/fix-net-err_cert_authority_invalid-error.html